# How to add a resource in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

How can I add the below resource in code behind?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="OpenHand" Cursor="pack://application:,,,/Resources/openhand.cur"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# Code-Behind, you can do like this:

```
ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary();
FrameworkElement fe = new FrameworkElement() 
{
   Cursor = new Cursor("pack://application:,,,/Resources/openhand.cur") 
};
rd.Add("OpenHand", fe);
Application.Current.Resources = rd;
```

If there are other ResourceDictionary in you Resources, you should **add rd into Resources**, not ***set Resources to rd***:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
            var res = new ResourceDictionary();
            var frame = new FrameworkElement() 
            {
             Cursor = new Cursor("pack://application:,,,/Resources/openhand.cur") 
            };
            res .Add("framework", frame);
            this.Resources.Add(rd);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var element = Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["OpenHand"] as FrameworkElement;
```